# Unexpected layout issue using GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am trying to get a JPane to fill up its given space, but it wont.
this code should be explanitary...

```
    JPanel memWindow = new JPanel();
    memWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
    memWindow.add(memField = new JTextField(10));
    memWindow.add(memView = new JButton("VM"));
    memWindow.add(memAdd = new JButton("M+"));
    memWindow.add(memSub = new JButton("M-"));

    JPanel memWindow2 = new JPanel();
    memWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
    memWindow.add(mem2Field = new JTextField(10));
    memWindow.add(mem2View = new JButton("VM"));
    memWindow.add(mem2Add = new JButton("M+"));
    memWindow.add(mem2Sub = new JButton("M-"));

    JPanel memWindows = new JPanel();
    memWindows.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    memWindows.add(memWindow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    memWindows.add(memWindow2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    add(displayWindow, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(memWindows);
    add(inputWindow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

this is the GUI i get...

[image]
.

Comment: I think I might have a better chance of helping you if I were to see the whole code

Comment: You haven't accepted any of the answers from your previous questions so I think I'll skip answering this one.

Comment: `memWindows.add(memWindow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` and `memWindows.add(memWindow2, BorderLayout.NORTH);` constraints have no meaning (`BorderLayout.XXX`)

Comment: Returning after 3 years, I now realise this question is terrible (one of my worst), and is affecting me negativly. Would it be better to delete?

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your code?

1.Can you explain following code first?

```
JPanel memWindow2 = new JPanel();
memWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
memWindow.add(mem2Field = new JTextField(10));
memWindow.add(mem2View = new JButton("VM"));
memWindow.add(mem2Add = new JButton("M+"));
memWindow.add(mem2Sub = new JButton("M-"));
```

I think it should be like this:

```
JPanel memWindow2 = new JPanel();
memWindow2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
memWindow2.add(mem2Field = new JTextField(10));
memWindow2.add(mem2View = new JButton("VM"));
memWindow2.add(mem2Add = new JButton("M+"));
memWindow2.add(mem2Sub = new JButton("M-"));
```

2.If you want to specify the component's position by using BorderLayout.XXX, you should use BorderLayout as following:

```
JPanel memWindows = new JPanel();
memWindows.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
memWindows.add(memWindow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
memWindows.add(memWindow2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```